# Reference to cells within several tables (named range within named range etc..)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, named-ranges

I'm writing a spreadsheet to track performance through time. As there is several iterations for each dates, it was way better for the eye to show each ones in a table and not everything in just one row. The result is a sheet where for each dates there is a table :

[image: FullData Sheet]

This is a reduced version for this present post, there is more columns and more rows for each dates (otherwise, yes, it could have been on one row only).

Each time we'll make a new evaluation, we'll copy a table in this FullData sheet, put it after the last one, and change the date.

As this sheet is very dense and because I'll later create graph of some indicators on time, I want to create a simplified sheet (Overview) that "receives" the data from the previous FullData sheet. The aimed table looks like this :

[image: Overview]

As you can see, the goal is to sum up each tables of the FullData sheet, in one row in the Overview sheet.

Ideally, it will automatically appear as a new line to the Overview, if there is a way to make it "detect" a new table/date.

I'm quite unskilled at spreadsheets. I get the mechanic but I'm super ignorant about the different functions. I explored around INDEX, Dynamic Cross Tables (I translate from french, not sure it's exactly the english name) and have the big intuition Named Ranges are in play here.

As the tables will always have the same size, there is maybe a way to indicate the date cell with a constant increment formula?

I get this isn't the only question here, It's my first post and feel free to tell me if it's not narrow enough, I just wanted to provide a wide view on the situation.

To sum up the questions I identify (for what I discover with spreadsheets, there is always a new question I didn't think about)

- **How to select the informations I want from the FullData sheet to the Overview one, in a way that will be easy to repeat each time I create a new table/date?**
- **Is this possible with the "basic" functions, avoiding macro/script (it would be another world to me)?**
- **Can automatic the process can be? Spectrum of automation : I just copy a new table with a new date and the selected data appear in the Overview <> I tweak the copied table each time, by naming it and/or adapt the formulas of it's original version.**

Thanks for your reading of my non-technical, non-totally english prose.

Comment: possible. share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Is it the good place to put it ? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-S2zBuQc1EQ6ExnYw3ApJVbQgfvRUbERBceGpToFwaE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({FullData!B2:B\ 
 {QUERY(FullData!L2:Q; "offset 2"; 0); 
 {""\""\""\""\""\"";""\""\""\""\""\""}}\ 
 {QUERY(FullData!L2:Q; "offset 3"; 0); 
 {""\""\""\""\""\"";""\""\""\""\""\"";""\""\""\""\""\""}}}; 
 "where Col1 is not null and not Col1 matches 'Amount|Duration'"; 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I think it works ! I mean it does. I have to adapt it to the full table but I think I understand how. 

Just one question, can you explain me how to understand these "{""\""\""\""\""\"";""\""\""\""\""\""}"  ? 
As we're in a query, does it mean we are importing the contents which are in two rows four columns ? I played a little with it, and I don't totally get the repetition of the offset, with the +1 increment of the {""\""\""\""\""\"";""\""\""\""\""\""}".

Thanks for the help !

Comment: all ranges/matrixes you put into array `{}` need to be of equal size. range `FullData!L2:Q` includes 6 columns therefore if you offset it by one row you need 6 empty cells at the bottom which is: `{""\""\""\""\""\""}`. we offset it by 2 rows then we need to add 2 empty rows so `{""\""\""\""\""\"";""\""\""\""\""\""}}`